# Is it possible to mirror (private self hosted gitlab) repos to codecommit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to o mirror (private self hosted gitlab) repos to codecommit, I've followed https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/push.html#set-up-a-push-mirror-from-gitlab-to-aws-codecommit

knowing that I have administrative access over the codecommit account, yet I keep getting the following error when I try to sync them.

`13:get remote references: create git ls-remote: exit status 128, stderr: "fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<repo-name>/': The requested URL returned error: 403\n".`

is it even possible to do this trough private self hosted gitlab?